# What is the difference of the meaning of 挂牌 in 挂牌督办 and 挂牌上市?

Tags: meaning-in-context

牌 is a sign or a board, 挂 is hanging, I understand that in a market where goods are to be sold, the seller would post a sign to tell potential buyers that here is the thing you want. But what is the sign of 督办 (supervision) posted? And where should the sign in this case posted? In the office? In a public square where everybody can see or on a LED screen of a train station?

Comment: are you talking about stock market? these terms used in the stock market.

Comment: 挂牌, there are same in 2 cases, that is 'put it in a list' (for trade or for action). e.g. 挂牌督办 means that put it into todo list.  挂牌上市 means your stock is listed in stock market.

Comment: @DanielYeung Do you mean other cases are not put into the to-do list?

Comment: 挂牌, literally, it means '把名字写在牌子上 (用来被检索查阅)", the usage starts in ancient, at that age some list are written in a wooden plaque / board for publicity.  nowadays, for a stock, it is for being searched for trading, so 挂牌上市 means listing your stock code & name in stock exchange for trading; 挂牌督办 means putting it into todo list for supervising implementation of a policy or execution of a task.

Comment: there are some other samples, e.g. if I start to run a company, I can say '挂牌营业' = 开业, I put my company name into a plaque and hang it at hall or door.

Answer (score 1):

**There won't be a real sign hanged.**

挂牌 originally means setting up a sign as you know. When use it in 挂牌督办, since only authority department can 督办, 挂牌 means the department show the case to public to urge other lower department which is in charge of the case.

The case under 挂牌督办 always has a deadline, so the lower department have to get it done in time, otherwise somebody would get things real bad.

As 挂牌上市, that is a totally different commercial definition, it means a company list their shares in stock market.

Comment: It could have been 限时督办if the deadline is stressed on.

Comment: pubic -> public.... And I cannot just edit to add one letter due to SE policy. lol

Comment: There will not be a real sign NOWADAYS. As @Daniel Yeung commented, this word is derivative from ancient meaning, it used to has a "board/kanban" things.